# Pattern Brush Doesn't Keep Original Shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I created a circle (using the shape tool and while holding down shift), and turned it into a pattern brush. Then I applied that pattern brush to another circle with the intent of getting a circle of circles, but it doesn't work like that. I tried adjusting the stroke, pattern scale, and pattern spacing, but to no avail. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a **scatter brush** if you want to conform to the object, use a **pattern brush** to conform to the *path.*

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the BLEND function to do this;

1. Create a blend between 2 circles : Object > Blend > Make
2. Set the blend options to set distance etc. : Object > Blend > Blend Options
3. Create the shape you want the blend to follow (in your example a bigger circle)
4. select your blended path and the shape you want the blend to be applied to and REPLACE SPINE : Object > Blend > Replace Spine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put.... Pattern Brushes will always distort a bit to fit a shape if they need to. **This is how Pattern Brushes work.**

Pattern tiles will **not** overlap, therefore if your base path is too small to allow full, and square, pattern tiles, the tiles are distorted to fit side-by-side. In your case, they create a rhomboid tile due to the curvature of the path.

Pattern brushes aren't designed to keep all tiles un-transformed. There is no way to stop this transformation in a pattern brush.

You may find a Scatter Brush works better for that particular use, although based upon the sample, I don't think I'd use any brush.